# Looping issue in nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js

I have a problem with nodejs. I'n try to read an xml file with node-xlsx library.

The libreary read correcly the file, and add info in array. the problem are when I try to mount other array with this array.

Code:

```
module.exports = {
  getConnections: function () {
    var obj = xlsx.parse('xxxxx.xls'); // parses a file
    var connection = {
      customer: "",
      Type: "",
      ip: "",
      user: "",
      pass: ""

    }
    var connections = [];
    //loop through all rows in the sheet
    for (var j = 0; j < obj[0]['data'].length; j ++) {
      //add the row to the rows array
      //rows.push(sheet['data'][j]);
      if (obj[0]['data'][j].length > 4) {
        var a = connection;
        connection.customer = obj[0]['data'][j][0];
        connection.Type = obj[0]['data'][j][2]
        connection.ip = obj[0]['data'][j][3]
        connection.user = j;
        connections.push(connection)
        //console.log(connection)
      }
    }
    console.log(connections)
    return connections;
  }
}
```

If I see the, console.log(connection), any object was correcly created. I add this object in array for return all info.

But If I read second console log, console.log(connections) for see what I return, all the objects in array are the same. All like the last value of for loop..

Comment: You are mutating the objects. Create it in the for loop instead of before it...